# Trouble with getting JSON in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to view the data retrieved from this function in order to parse the json, but I can't view the 'data' within the function. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbbc7/4/

```js
$.getJSON("api.forrst.com/api/v2/user/posts?username=_max&callback=?", function(data) {
    #("forrst").append(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forrst">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably meant

```
$("#forrst").append(data);
```

instead of

```
#("forrst").append(data);
```

And you need to specify which key exactly you want to append. For example,

```
$("#forrst").append(data.resp.posts[0].id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbbc7/10/

Comment: Thanks, would you mind updating it to loop through all of the posts?

Comment: @XcodeDev: See the examples in the jQuery `getJSON` documentation using the `each` method: http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson. They're pretty straight-forward

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one,

```
#("forrst").append(data);
```

should be

```
$("#forrst").append(data);
```

And, [as genesis-φ points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719309/trouble-with-getting-json-in-jquery/7719349#7719349), you need to specify what exactly you're appending to the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.forrst.com/api/v2/user/posts?username=_max&callback=?", function(data) {
    $.each(data.resp.posts, function(index, val){
        $("#forrst").append("<h2><a href='" + val.post_url + "'>" + val.title + "</a></h2>")
        $('#forrst').append(val.formatted_description);
        $('#forrst').append("<hr>");
    });
});
```